# Audio Frequency Shift Keying to Arduino

Tags: arduino, audio, frequency

I am attempting to have an Arduino interpret an AFSK signal, this is very vague but can anyone just point me in the right direction for detecting the frequency of the AFSK signal with an arduino?

Answer (score 3):

Can you give any more detail on the frequency of the signal. A 60 and 100 Hz signal is a different ball game than 60 and 61 Hz which is significantly harder to diagnose and is completely different from 6 and 7 GHz.

For 60 and 100Hz of dependable amplitude I would just use a schmitt trigger and count the time between rising edges.
-Max Murphy

Comment: its 4000 and 8000hz

Comment: Schmitt trigger plus counting times between rising edges. One will be double the other. If the amplitude of your signal give trouble, just through it through an amp, if you need a design, I can toss you one.

Comment: design help would be AWESOME amplitude is an issue and I was thinking about using an amp.

Comment: What kind of information do you have about the amplitude, if it is wildly varying there are a lot of ways to approach it. the schmitt trigger approach really does better if both signals would have the same amplitude.

If they will both have the same amplitude, but just need an amp, that is very easy to do, and I can honestly give you some very simple methods to do such.

Comment: I know the information is vague, if you are needing an amp that is simple to build, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter will get the job done. I love to build them, and often with only two resistors.
If you need more help getting it working, let me know, but often it is as simple as pretending the base emitter junction is .7 and picking voltages that work for you and matching them with resistors.

Answer (score 1):

At the 4000Hz and 8000Hz, you're looking at 125 microseseconds and 62.5 microseconds pulse width, respectively.  That might be slow enough for [Arduino's built-in pulseIn() function](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn).  There's some setup and teardown time of the function, so if your signal switches between 4kHz & 8kHz too rapidly, you might miss some bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using two op amps in a band-pass configuration.  This would allow you to split the AFSK signal into two separate amplitude modulated signals.  As a bonus, you could also amplify the input signal if it's too low.